# HTML <textarea> does not respect "flex-grow"

Tags: html, css

In the below snippet you can see the `<div>` grows, but the `<textarea>` does not, why? It is the same in Chrome and Firefox.

```css
details {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
}

div, textarea {
  display: block;
  flex-grow:1;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 32px;
}
```

```html
<details open>
    <summary>
    Summary
    </summary>
    <textarea>text area does not grow</textarea>
    <div>Div does grow</div>
</details>
```

Answer (score 1):

All html inputs(including `textarea`) have some sort of fixed width by default hence why the flex-grow seems to not to do anything until you change the width to 100%

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

details {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
}

div, textarea {
  display: block;
  flex-grow:1;
  background: green;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<details open>
    <summary>
    Summary
    </summary>
    <textarea>text area does grow</textarea>
    <div>Div does grow</div>
</details>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the setting the width to 100% before posting the question, but unfortunately in my application, I have 32px left margin, so then it goes beyond the right edge. Is there a way to undo the browsers width style? At the moment I am doing `width: calc(100% - 32px);` which does not seem great to me.

Comment: I've edited the answer it removes the browsers default style hence it should fix you 32px margin now